# ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar vs BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor

Tags: spring, spring-4

My use case deals with creating beans dynamically. I find they are two options to register bean definitions:
`ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar` and `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor`

I wanted to understand the difference between two.

Thanks,
Prateek

Answer (score 0):

The BeanDefinitionRegistrar must be used with @Import annotation

```
@Configuration
@Import(MyImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar.class)
public class MainConfiguration {

}
```

while the BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor should be used like that

```
@Bean
public static MyBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor myBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor() {
    return new MyBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor();
}
```

However on spring 3.2.16 both fails to modify my own bean definitions created with @Bean, they seemed to be called to early.

Answer (score 0):

with ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar, you can fetch annotation metadata of the importing class, such as value of @MapperScan